# mySQL Easier Way to do Mutliple Statments?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a page on my site I'm using to edit articles in my CMS. My site currently has two different `sql` statements and I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? What I'm doing is using the first statement to populate all the fields in my form but I'm using a second statement for my categories `select` input so I can `loop` all the different `options` here my code, basically I'm wondering if there away to do this with only 1 `sql` statement, thanks in advance so much!

**TABLE CATEGORIES**

```
cat_id  cat_name
1       soccer
2       baseball
3       baketball
```

**TABLE ARTICLES**

```
art_id  art_cat_id  art_title  art_slug  art_company  
1       1           lorem      lorem     lorem
```

**HTML / PHP**

```
<?php
 $sql_articles = "SELECT art_id, art_cat_id, art_title, art_slug, art_company, cat_id, cat_name
                FROM app_articles LEFT JOIN app_categories
                ON app_articles.art_cat_id = app_categories.cat_id
                WHERE art_id =".$_GET['art_id']; 

$result = query($sql_articles);
if($result===false) {
    echo("query failed");
}
else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)              
?>

<form id="articles" action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['art_title']; ?>">

<input type="text" name="slug" value="<?php echo $row['art_slug']; ?>"> 

<input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $row['art_company']; ?>">

<select name="category">
    <option value="<?php echo $row['art_cat_id'] ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row['cat_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    $sql_categories = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM app_categories";

    $result = query($sql_categories);

    if($result===false) {
            echo("Query Fail");
    }
    else {
        while( $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row['art_cat_id'] == $data['cat_id']) continue;
    ?>     
            <option value="<?php echo $data['cat_id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['cat_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    }
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

**My First Statement Returns**

```
art_id  art_cat_id  art_title  art_slug  art_company cat_id  cat_name
1       1           lorem      lorem     lorem       1       soccer
```

**What I need is something like this I guess**

```
art_id  art_cat_id  art_title  art_slug  art_company cat_id  cat_name
1       1           lorem      lorem     lorem       1       soccer
                                                     2       baseball
                                                     3       basketball
```

Is that even possible to do in one query though? Thanks

Comment: You have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Load up all your data in the first query, then extract as required?

Comment: @DarylGill that's what I was thinking but the problem I run into with that is I'm using `WHERE art_id =._GET['art_id']` so that limits my results to the category that is used for the article only, that's why I did the second statement so I could get all the records and loop them. Is there a better solution to this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself constantly writing queries which are pulling information from the same table with the same `where` clause, then you could produce one statement, to pull all relivant data out of the database in one pull. Then use

`$Statement->data_seek(0); // Returns to the first row`

to re-use your statement. Providing that you have not issued:

`$Statement->close();`

But coming from your comment. I quote:

*@DarylGill that's what I was thinking but the problem I run into with that is I'm using `WHERE art_id =._GET['art_id']` so that limits my results to the category that is used for the article only, that's why I did the second statement so I could get all the records and loop them. Is there a better solution to this, thanks!*

There is some options, by using an associative array:

`$Var = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

then perform a

```
print_r($Var);
```

You will notice that the array key names will match column names from your MySQL Table.

From this you can work with this array as you see fit, using a simple:

```
foreach ($Var AS $Keys => $Value)
{
  if ($Keys == 'CatExample')
  {
    echo $Value; // This will output everyting with the keyname of 'CatExample'
  }
}
```

or another method, that you find by experimenting.

Comment: I still don't really understand because even if I use associated array my data from that sql will only be with the fields corresponding with article fields and I wont get the result with all the categories only the category that matches the article

Comment: Select all items from the database, use a while loop to build an array. Then perform a foreachloop to select only the necessary information

Comment: Okay thanks, so I don't limit it in the sql ill limit the data in `foreach` , thanks I was just confused for a sec, thanks for your time!

Comment: Test it out, just so I know I am right with how I would approach a method like this. If it does not work how you are expecting. I will modify my answer based on the code you provide

Comment: I have it working so I can get all the categories now thank you, but how can I only get the results for where the `art_id` = the id I'm passing through the url, thanks so much!